# How to add context menu to wpf datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

How does one add a `ContextMenu` to a `DataGrid`? I want to be able to right click anywhere on the DataGrid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding different context menu for datagrid's header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706246/adding-different-context-menu-for-datagrids-header)

Answer (score 166):

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Click Me" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You can add a checkbox to the MenuItem by adding IsCheckable="true"