# contextmenu datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding different context menu for datagrid’s header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706246/adding-different-context-menu-for-datagrids-header)

I have datagrid, but in context menu I want to see my own fields(not Copy Cut Paste) Can anybody help me to do this,please&

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an implicit style. In your controls resources add the following:

```
<Style
 TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
 <Setter
    Property="ContextMenu">
 <Setter.Value>
   <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="First One" />
      <MenuItem Header="Second One" />
   </ContextMneu>
 </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note: If you want this to be on say a TextBox (because that is what you are showing in Edit mode) just change the TargetType line to be {x:Type TextBox} or whatever other control you want.

Answer (score 0):

post some source code please. this works for me:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
      <!-- your menu stuff goes here -->
   <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```